# Strip queries in my URLs in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, strip

I want to strip unwanted facebook queries from my URLs for SEO reasons.

So this is what I have know, and it's working quite well:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fb_.*$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=302,L]

BUT on the mobile version of my website it redirects http://m.website.com/filename.html?fb_source=blabla to http://www.website.com/m/filename.html

How can I fix this please?

Comment: What is it _supposed_ to rewrite to?

Comment: it needs to rewrite to http://m.website.com/filename.html ... and http://blabla.website.com/filename.html?fb_source=dsfdf to http://blabla.website.com/filename.html

Comment: It seems to be some kind of interaction with the rewrite for your mobile site. You may need to show that too.